# Responsive navigation menu is hiding on swipe

Tags: jquery, css, navigationbar

The menu is beautiful and works beautifully on a desktop. On a mobile however it works well until you scroll (swipe up or down).
Please help me figure out how to solve this.

I am also using a resize functiion to make it look better

```
            function resizer() {
                var $ul = $("#cssmenu ul");
                var ulWidth = 0;
                $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
                    ulWidth = ulWidth + $(this).width()
                });
                if ($(window).width() > 1600) {
                    $("#cssmenu > ul").css('width', ulWidth + 600);
                    $("#cssmenu").css('width', ulWidth + 600);
                    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").css('padding-right', '60px');
                } else if ($(window).width() > 1300) {
                    $("#cssmenu > ul").css('width', ulWidth + 300);
                    $("#cssmenu").css('width', ulWidth + 300);
                    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").css('padding-right', '30px');
                } else if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
                    $("#cssmenu > ul").css('width', ulWidth + 100);
                    $("#cssmenu").css('width', ulWidth + 100);
                    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").css('padding-right', '10px');
                } else if ($(window).width() > 900) {
                    $("#cssmenu > ul").css('width', ulWidth);
                    $("#cssmenu").css('width', ulWidth);
                    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").css('padding-right', '0');
                } else {
                    $("#cssmenu > ul").css('width', '100%');
                    $("#cssmenu").css('width', '100%');
                };
            };


 $(window).resize(function() {
            resizer();
        });




 $(document).ready(function() {
            resizer();
        });
```

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

    var cssmenu = $(this),
      settings = $.extend({
        title: "Bebemoda",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + '</div>');
      $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {

          mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
        } else {
          mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });

      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
          } else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
          }
        });
      };

      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
      else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

      if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

      resizeFix = function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 800) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }

        if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

    });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "multitoggle"
      });

      $("#cssmenu").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

      var foundActive = false,
        activeElement, linePosition = 0,
        menuLine = $("#cssmenu #menu-line"),
        lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

      $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
          activeElement = $(this);
          foundActive = true;
        }
      });

      if (foundActive === false) {
        activeElement = $("#cssmenu > ul > li").first();
      }

      defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

      defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

      menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
      menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

      $("#cssmenu > ul > li").hover(function() {
          activeElement = $(this);
          lineWidth = activeElement.width();
          linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
          menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
          menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
        },
        function() {
          menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
          menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
        }
      );

    });


  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 #cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
{
  max-width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #009ae1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #009ae1;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 18px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 6px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #009ae1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  z-index: 5;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 32px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #009ae1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li,
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-line {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px;
    top: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cssmenu">
  <div id="menu-line" style="width: 100px; left: 0px;"></div>
  <div id="menu-button" class=""></div>
  <ul>


    <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="/furniture">Furniture</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li><a href="/furniture/cots-beds">Cots and Beds</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/furniture/high-chairs">High Chairs</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/furniture/activity">Activity</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/furniture/seating">Soft Seating</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/furniture/wardrobes">Wardrobes</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/furniture/shelves-drawers">Shelves and Drawers</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/furniture/changing-tables">Changing Tables</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="/travel">Travel</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li><a href="/travel/mutsy-prams">Mutsy Prams</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/travel/mutsy-pushchairs">Mutsy Pushchairs</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/travel/essentials">Travel Essentials</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/travel/mutsy-accessories">Mutsy Accessories</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/travel/mutsy-prams/igo">Mutsy Igo</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/travel/mutsy-prams/evo">Mutsy Evo</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/travel/mutsy-prams/exo">Mutsy Exo</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/travel/mutsy-car-seats/safe2go">Mutsy Safe2Go</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="/decor">Decor</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li><a href="/decor/cushions-and-pillows">Cushions</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/decor/floor">Floor</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/decor/lighting">Lighting</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/decor/mobiles">Mobiles</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/decor/rugs">Rugs</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/decor/wall-art">Wall Art</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/decor/wall-decals">Wall Decals</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="/gear">Gear</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li><a href="/gear/mutsy-pushchairs">Pushchairs</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/gear/backpacks">Backpacks</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/gear/bags">Bags</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/gear/bouncers">Bouncers</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/gear/changing">Changing</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/gear/floor-activity">Floor Activity</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/gear/carriers">Carriers</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="/bath-and-potty">Bath</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li><a href="/bath-and-potty/body-care">Body Care</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/bath-and-potty/changing">Changing</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/bath-and-potty/potties">Potties</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/bath-and-potty/storage">Storage</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/bath-and-potty/towels">Towels</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/bath-and-potty/toys">Toys</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/bath-and-potty/tubs">Tubs</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/bath-and-potty/wash-n-scrub">Wash 'n Scrub</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/bath-and-potty/safety">Health and Safety</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="/feeding">Feeding</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li><a href="/feeding/bibs">Bibs</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/feeding/dishes-and-sets">Dishes and Sets</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/feeding/high-chairs">High Chairs</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/feeding/lunch-bags">Lunch Bags</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/feeding/nursing-covers">Nursing Covers</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="/apparel">Apparel</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li><a href="/apparel/backpacks">Backpacks</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/apparel/sleepwear">Sleepwear</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="/toys">Toys</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="/toys/blocks-and-games">Blocks and Games</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/push-and-pull">Push and Pull</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/transport">Transport</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/rattles">Rattles</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/outdoor">Outdoor</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/art">Art</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/musical">Musical</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/pram-toys">Pram Toys</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/ride-on">Ride on</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/magnetic">Magnetic</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/toys/wooden">Wooden</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="/storage">Storage</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">

        <li><a href="/storage/bath">Bath</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/storage/kitchen">Kitchen</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/storage/playroom">Playroom</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/outlet">Outlet</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it might be due to the fact that on some mobiles ( e.g. iPhones ), scrolling triggers resize event. Most menus have resize event handlers, which hide the menu if window width is less than a certain width. They do so, in order to keep the menu hidden ( or collapsed ) in mobile view by default.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I tried without the resizing script and still no success. It is something else.